# Is Juvenoia a real world?

Tags: is-it-a-word

I have recently watched a Vsauce video titled 'Juvenoia'. In video he says that Juvenoia is fear of an older generation that the generation after them is worse and less wise than them. After trying to translate that word in various languages, I failed. So, is Juvenoia a real word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although is not in dictionaries like Oxford or Cambridge, you might consider it a real word given that it has currency. It has entries in [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=juvenoia) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/juvenoia).

It is a portmanteau, i.e. a blend, of *juvenile* and *paranoia*. That said, it isn't a very elegant blend.

It is an uncountable noun.

Comment: So me using in in writing tests or smt won't be a mistake?

Comment: Not it won't be but not every one knows the word so it depends on context.You may have to explain it basically.For example there are words in German expressin' strange and complex feelings.Such as scheduenfreude look it up.

Comment: @Jon Snow's papa 'So me using in in writing tests or smt won't be a mistake?' _ It might well lose you a mark if the person marking your work doesn't find it in OED. Does that constitute a mistake?

Comment: @aintnosunshinewhenyouaregone Looking _scheduenfreude_ won’t do you much good; it’s _schadenfreude_.